# Azure ServiceDefinition vmsize

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Is there a way to define and change the VMSIZE in the Service Definition file *.csdef by choosing different configurations (not manually)?

We have a debug test environment which we can publish to using multiple Service Configuration files (*.cscfg), but when we go to production deployments we would like to automatically have the vmsize change based on our requirements. These requirements are known in advanced and don't need to by dynamic, just that deploying to our test development environment vs. production we would like to automatically change the vmsize.

Is this possible to change without manually editing the *.csdef file ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to change the VM size automatically with Cloud Services. VM size is defined in `csdef` file and this file must be updated, repackaged and redeployed for new VM size. In short, automatic scaling out is allowed in Cloud Services but not scaling up/down.

In one of the projects where we used Cloud Services, we ended up creating multiple cloud projects (one for each environment) and used the project based on the environment in which we were deploying the code.

Comment: I figured as much, but was hoping there was a way around that. Thank you for your answer.